# Synchronizing the table structure between two sql server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using two databases `test` and `prod` in the same SQL Server instance. The databases share the same data structure but contains different data, is there an easy way to synchronize the structure between the two so if I modify a table in `test` automatically update also the same table in `prod`?

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way round. Every change to the database structure (tables, indexes, views, procedures) must be done through a script that is stored in a version control system (Subversion, Git, ..) then you only need to apply the correct scripts on prod and you are done. There are tools to help you with that, e.g. Liquibase or Flyway. Comparing them _after_ you have done "uncontrolled" changes to one environment will always get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a trigger on the table in test which uses a MERGE to update the table in prod... 
I would be careful of persisting changes made in a test environment to a prod environment automatically though.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to duplicate the data I need to syncronize the table structure